# CCNP ENCORという試験のPythonの問題でわからないところがあり、投稿させて頂きます。 問題はこちらになります。

Tags: python

展示を参照してください。無効になっているインターフェースの説明のみを出力するPythonコードスニペットはどれですか ?
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

選択肢 A:

```
for interface in netconf_data["GigabitEthernet"]:
    print(interface["enabled"])
    print(interface["description"])
```

選択肢 B:

```
for interface in netconf_data["GigabitEthernet"]:
    if interface["disabled"] != 'true':
    print(interface["description"])
```

選択肢 C:

```
for interface in netconf_data["GigabitEthernet"]:
    if interface["enabled"] != 'true':
        print(interface["description")
```

選択肢 D:

```
for interface in netconf_data["GigabitEthernet"]:
    if interface["enabled"] != 'false':
        print(interface["description"])
```

この問題の正解がサイトごとで違う為、どれが正解なのかがわかりません。

参考サイトはこちらになります。

https://itexamanswers.net/ccie-ccnp-350-401-encor-dumps-full-questions-with-vce-pdf.html/2

こちらの379番目の問題になります。

ちなみに私は、Dの解答にしました。

この問題がわからなければ、CCNP ENCORは不合格になってしまいます。

どうかお知恵をお貸し下さい。
よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: Cの「print(interface["description")」はコピペミスですか？

Comment: そうですね。私のコピーミスです。回答群の文字が画像になっていたので、画像の文字を抽出して貼り付けたら、Cは［ ］が抜けていました。

Answer (score 0):

**正解は C** のはずです。disabled であるものだけをピックアップするための if の条件節について、

```
interface["enabled"] != 'true'
```

要するに `interface["enabled"] == 'false'`、つまり **disabled** ✅

一方 D は

```
interface["enabled"] != 'false'
```

要するに `interface["enabled"] == 'true'`、つまり **enabled** ❌

---

参考までに、A はそもそも if を使っていません（❌）し、B は、if ブロックの使い方が間違っています（字下げがない）（❌）。

Comment: @hataさん
ありがとうございます。
だいぶ理解できました。
全くわからず苦戦していました。
本当に理解できるようになり感謝です。
どうもありがとうございます。

Comment: こちらを参考に。[自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)